# Getting 301 moved permanently error on woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, woocommerce

I am using customize `wirecard payment gateway` in woocommerce plugin. Currently when i go on checkout page and submit the `confirm pay button` after filling all information(e.g.-credit card no, card holder name ) the check page is being stuck and not process further. I have checked in firebug for error(response) then its giving `301 moved permanently` status. 
My site is ssl secure with https.

Url for test product: https://example.com/testprod

You can fill the `dummy billing address` and all information (use `postal code- GL51 3AA`)

dummy payment details:

```
Creditcard Holder Name   : John Doe
Creditcard Number        : 4222222222222
Expiration Date          : Month: 1, Year: 2015
CCV Code                 : 100
```

I have used the code `$processurl = WC_Compat_Wirecard::force_https( add_query_arg('wc-api', 'WC_Gateway_Wirecard_ProcessPayment', home_url( '/' ) ) );` 
for processing ajax url and it is giving
the output url as https://example.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Wirecard_ProcessPayment
but when i inspected process in chrome browser it response is

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Wirecard_ProcessPayment. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

while my return url is `https://example.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Wirecard_ProcessPayment`

Thanks in advance for any solution/suggestion.

**Note: If any more information required please ask.**

Comment: have you tried htaccess rule to force SSL

Comment: yes i have tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `https://` in your ajax request

So, remove https:// and leave it with only domain name.

### For Dynamic domain

You can get it with wordpress `home_url()` ane then parse it with `parse_url()`

```
e.g. $new_home_url = parse_url(home_url());
```

change `home_url( '/' )` in `$processurl` with `$new_home_url`